# COUNT values in one Column for Distinct Value in Another Column - EXCEL

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, countif, distinct-values

**Hello All,**

I have two columns in Excel Worksheet and want to count column 2 for distinct values in Column 1.

**Table:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Yes |
| Orange | Yes |
| Apple | Yes |
| Banana | No |
| Grapes | No |
| Banana | No |
| Orange | Yes |

**Desired OUTPUT / RESULT:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| YES | 2 |
| NO | 2 |

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: `Yes` count should be 2, how it is 3?

Comment: You are right. my bad.

Comment: So, try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8=E2)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8&""))
```

[image]

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then use below formulas-

```
E2=UNIQUE(B2:B8)
F2=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8=E2)))
```